Connecting to Mysql from java jar run in Linux Ubuntu 20.04 not connecting
The real world problem is allowing a java maven build to create an executable application jar and then inserting data about the jar into a mysql database. The SQL connection and inserts work properly in windows without any problems. But when this is deployed and ran on Linux it always returns a null connection and entries cannot be made into the database. The connection uses the below connection string which works fine in the glassfish connection pools server and port 127.0.0.1:3306. So I assume there is nothing wrong there.
To trace down where the problem is, I created a simple executable jar connecting to a MySql database. A user was also created for the database connection as follows:
CREATE USER 'dbUser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'dbUserPWD';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON test_db.* TO 'dbUser'@'localhost';

The connection string is as follows :
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/@DB?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true

The actual app connecting to the database is as follows :
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DbConnect {

    private static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/@DB?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true";
    
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String db = args[0];
        String user = args[1];
        String pwd = args[2];
        Connection con = null;
        
        System.out.println("DB CONNECTION TEST RUNNING");
        System.out.println("DB : " + db + " - User : " + user + " - Pwd : " + pwd);
        
        try {

            con = getDBConnection(db, user, pwd);
            
            if (con != null) {
                if (con.isValid(10)) {
                    
                    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
                    ResultSet rs = null;

                    String sql = "SHOW TABLES";

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    try {
                        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

                        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                        int count = 0;
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            count++;
                            if(count == 1){
                                sb.append(rs.getString(1));
                            }else{
                                sb.append(", ").append(rs.getString(1));
                            }
                        }

                        System.out.println("Tables Count : " + count);
                        System.out.println("Tables : " + sb);

                        rs.close();
                        stmt.close();

                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Exception : " + ex.getMessage());
                    }                     
                    
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Connection Invalid");
                }
                con.close();
            }else{
                System.out.println("Connection Null");
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception : " + ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (con != null){
                try{
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex){
                    System.out.println("Exception : " + ex.getMessage());        
                }
            }
        }        
    }
    
    public static Connection getDBConnection(String db, String user, String pwd) {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("NOT FOUND DB_DRIVER : " + DB_DRIVER);
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("DB_CONNECTION STRING : " + DB_CONNECTION.replace("@DB", db));
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION.replace("@DB", db), user, pwd);
            return conn;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
        return conn;
    }
        
}

It is then executed at commandline with the following call :
java -jar dbconnectiontester.jar "testDB" "dbUser" "dbUserPWD"

This way I can simply demonstrate the scenario in the Maven build context.
It works without any problems in Windows but does not in Linux Ubuntu 20.04
Could the above example be refused connection because of some kind of Linux user permissions problem I am not aware of.
Your input would be greatly appreciated.
Checked in user permissions in SQL :
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'dbUser'@'localhost';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for dbUser@localhost                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `dbUser`@`localhost`                                  |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `testDB`.* TO `dbUser`@`localhost`  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

When I run (changed password) :
java -jar dbconntester.jar "testDB" "dbUser" "dbUser@PWD000"
DB CONNECTION TEST RUNNING
DB : testDB - User : dbUser - Pwd : dbUser@PWD000
DB_CONNECTION STRING : jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testDB?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
Tables Count : 0
Tables :
So connecting to mysql from a JAR works without issue.
I will have to look into my actual problem to do with the maven builds.
Thanks

Sharing the error messages you get will be helpful.

Also if you don't get any useful error messages (e.g. I see you're cathing a SQLException without printing anything to stderr / stdout in getDBConnection, which may hide a crucial error), try and run the thing in a debugger / log stuff to stderr. If this boils down to a problem with the app, the question is ought to be closed here. But yes, we need error messages.
